# Issue in getting Access Token from Windows Azure Media service Using REST API?

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-media-services

I Use below REST call to get the access token from WMS, the problem is, some times it works sometimes it  gives error `"A server with the specified hostname could not be found"`, Everything is same but the output is random, why this happens ? I'm using c# console project to make this request.

```
POST https://wamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: wamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net
Content-Length: 120
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: application/json
Body:grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=ams_account_name&client_secret=URL_encoded_ams_account_key&scope=urn%3aWindowsAzureMediaServices
```

Comment: You can find implementation details of how WAMS.NET SDK getting a token by looking into https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-media-services/blob/dev/src/net/Client/MediaServicesCredentials.cs. I am not seeing problems with your request, does WebClient gives you ""A server with the specified hostname could not be found" error or it is part o acs response body. It seems you have network connectivity/dns issues.try to use https://wamsprodglobal002acs.accesscontrol.windows.net if it will make any difference.

Comment: Thanks,I got that as an error. If there is any connectivity or dns then the error should occur every time, but i'm getting the access token some times and error some other time. What is the difference between 2 urls ?

Comment: Second url is secondary endpoint which should act in a same way as primary. You can fallback on it if for some reason primary has issues. You should not see such error rate in first place and based on your error message it seems that there are  some networking issues .Did you ty running your code in a cloud or ouside your network?